# Two images different in chrome the same in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, photoshop

I have very werid problem with my image, i have two version of it, they both look the same in windows image viewer, and every image editor, but they look differnt in chrom, the same IE, and different in FireFox, how is this possible ?

just open them in separate tabs and compare color in background
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsqEO.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtOah.jpg

Comment: The colors are the same for me in chrome and firefox. The only difference is the size of the black boxes

Comment: for me they look different, can I do sth with my browsers ? I use chrom 33 and IE 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What application was used to generate and/or manipulate the jpeg images?

I have had similar problem once before and it turned out to be something as simple as the color space the image was saved with. The image was saved with an ICC profile that applications interpreted differently.

A simple way to test this would be to open your jpegs in Photoshop, then go save as, and on the save as dialog uncheck the color profile box and try that out. If they are still different something else is going on but this will at least allow you to rule out the ICC color profile being the issue.

For the most part color profiles are something none of us ever usually have to worry about as there is a generic default profile. Some applications are profile aware and others are not which is why you will sometimes see images differently if saved with a profile that one application recognizes while another does not.

Comment: i have no idea, but I opened them in paint.net and saved as other files and there was still diference, them same using photoshop , I spent on it some time allready. But do you see any difference or not as someone mentioned in first comment ?

Comment: On my screen both look identical - only difference is the size of the black boxes.

If you have access to Photoshop, open your jpeg, then go save as, and on the save as dialog uncheck the color profile box and try that out. If they are still different something else is going on but this will at least allow you to rule out the ICC color profile being the issue.

Comment: wow, I see now that default as I want to save one has this option selected, and other not, and I just tried save with this option as unselected and it works, both are the same, could you edit your answer and say more about this option and how it is possible that other dont't see the difference? Has this option to do sth with operating system ? That only I can see this ?

Comment: and better with this option selected on both or unselected ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I had similar problem with image in both browser then i saw above answer and The image was saved with an ICC profile that applications interpreted differently.

But after unchecked of checkbox also it was not working so i tried saving JPEG format with **Export > Save for web** and now it displays properly in both browsers.